# Adding a resource generator to all scopes in SBT

Tags: sbt

I have a resource generator which should run both for `Compile` and for `Test`. The code looks like this:

```
resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val source = (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "isabelle"
  val target = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "isabelle"
  if (source.exists()) {
    log.info(s"Copying Isabelle sources from $source to $target")
    IO.delete(target)
    IO.copyDirectory(source, target)
    val files = (target ** "*").get.filter(_.isFile)
    val mapper = Path.rebase(target, "")
    val contents = files.map(mapper).map(_.get).mkString("\n")
    val list = target / ".libisabelle_files"
    IO.write(list, contents)
    list +: files
  }
  else {
    Nil
  }
}.taskValue
```

Essentially, it looks for all files in the `src/main/isabelle` folder, copies it over to `resources_managed/main/isabelle` and additionally writes a list of these files.

This works fine so far, but I would also like to support `src/test/isabelle`. Obviously, I could copy the above code, but that seems hardly elegant (even if I pull out the common bits into a function).

I tried removing `in Compile` everywhere, but that didn't work (`"References to undefined settings"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `inConfig`:

```scala
val isabelleSettings = Seq(
  resourceGenerators += Def.task {
    val log = streams.value.log
    val source = sourceDirectory.value / "isabelle"
    val target = resourceManaged.value / "isabelle"
    if (source.exists()) {
      log.info(s"Copying Isabelle sources from $source to $target")
      IO.delete(target)
      IO.copyDirectory(source, target)
      val files = (target ** "*").get.filter(_.isFile)
      val mapper = Path.rebase(target, "")
      val contents = files.map(mapper).map(_.get).mkString("\n")
      val list = target / ".libisabelle_files"
      IO.write(list, contents)
      list +: files
    }
    else {
      Nil
    }
  }.taskValue
)

inConfig(Compile)(isabelleSettings)
inConfig(Test)(isabelleSettings)
```

see:

```
> test:products
[info] Copying Isabelle sources from /Users/dnw/Desktop/t-2016-02-22.1038/src/test/isabelle to /Users/dnw/Desktop/t-2016-02-22.1038/target/scala-2.11/resource_managed/test/isabelle
[info] Copying Isabelle sources from /Users/dnw/Desktop/t-2016-02-22.1038/src/main/isabelle to /Users/dnw/Desktop/t-2016-02-22.1038/target/scala-2.11/resource_managed/main/isabelle
```